# Custom domain certificate error • Server's certificate (heroku) does not match the URL www.app.com

Tags: ruby-on-rails, security, heroku, dns, certificate

I made a web app using heroku and I set up the custom domain as per there instructions here: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/custom-domains

Now in chrome my Https is crossed out and it says:

```
The identity of this website has not been verified 
• Server's certificate does not match the URL.

You attempted to reach www.app.com, but instead you actually reached a server
identifying itself as *.herokuapp.com. This may be caused by a misconfiguration
on the server. Cannot verify that that is the same site as www.app.com
```

I don't think I missed a step. Do I have to renew a certificate using heroku certs? or self sign my own? or what? thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want SSL on your custom domain too, you have to follow the [SSL guide](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ssl#customdomain-ssl) also.

Comment: Any clue why i get these errors on the first commands in the guide?
mv: rename server.key to server.orig.key: No such file or directory and
Error opening Private Key server.orig.key

Answer (score 0):

ssl certs are to specific domains.  m.yourdomain.com will not accept the cert from yourdomain.com.

Sounds like your problem.  You could get a wildcard cert, so *yourdomain.com, although, those are costly!